# How to configure Apache mod_pagespeed to disable filters for specific URL?

Tags: apache, config, mod-pagespeed

I wanna enable filter [**defer_javascript**](https://modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-js-defer) on whole site (Wordpress) except every urls ending with `/amp/` to avoid violating AMP-HTML rules (*user-defined javascripts*). I've tried to put these into my vhost config

```
<LocationMatch "/amp">
    ModPagespeedDisableFilters defer_javascript 
</LocationMatch>
```

But that isn't worked.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create another .htaccess inside the folder and disable the Pagespeed filter afterwards

Comment: thank you so much. But after all I've migrate my webserver to nginx, so I've done that stuff easier :))